# Not able to save Azure Logic Apps standard workflow in VS Code after adding Scope shape

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

This seems very simple, all I am trying is to add a scope shape in the designer of Logic App Standard VS Code and it doesn't get saved whereas without Scope it is saving the workflow. Is this a bug or am i missing something?

without Scope section just with the actions it does save, Anyone else facing this issue?

[image]

I tried with and without Scope action on the Designer.

I expected Both to save as normal whereas it doesn't.

Comment: As of today this started happening to me for standard logic apps. I've been heavily developing logic apps for 6 weeks, and just this afternoon I can't save anything... Doesn't matter whether it's in a scope section or not!

I noticed the little save dialog doesn't popup on this workflow anymore, whereas it does on other logic app workflows that are saving OK. I've restarted, reinstalled the extension, tried an older version and no luck... I suspect there's an error in the JSON that it's not notifying about properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my (similar) issue. It turns out there was an invalid parameter, but because the parameter was edited by the extension without me manually making changes, it didn't trigger the validation, and I wasn't notified in any way.

My case was a conditional express as below, where the value I entered was the literal string `null`, but this keeps getting removed:

[image: null text removed from conditional expression1]

Once I found and fixed the error (by deleting actions one-by-one until I could save) then I can save again as usual.